# Save one column of specific row to a .txt file in datagrid (Error: Unable to cast object of type App.Data.Controller to type System.Data.Datarowview)

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, datagrid

I've been looking around for a tutorial on how to do this since I'm quite new at working with WPF but cant find to seem what I'm looking for.

I have a datagrid binded and filled with testdata. I also have a download button per row that is meant to only download the column "XMLCode" of the row it belongs to. I would like for this data to be downloaded in a .txt file.

I know that proper architecture is MVVM but for simplicity's sake I care about getting the function to work first. Than rebuilding it into MVVM at a later time. I think my issue sounds simple enough but I can't find any tutorial or help that only deals with one specific column in one specific row, only examples of downloading an entire datagrid to a .txt file. Could anyone help me in the right direction?

Datagrid code for clarification

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" x:Name="ConDatagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AllDatainTable, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.LabelNaam}" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Header="XML" Binding="{Binding XMLCode}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.LabelDownload}" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.IsFilterVisible="False" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="DLButton_Click" Content="{iconPacks:Material Kind=ContentSave, Width=16, Height=16}">
                            <!-- Click=""> -->
                        </Button >
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

EDIT : This is what I've tried so far with a different table, this wields the error "Unable to cast object of type App.Data.Controller to type System.Data.Datarowview"

```
    public static void DumpAsTxt(object data, string fileName)
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    private void DLButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                System.Data.DataRowView dataRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;
                String ControllerID = dataRowView[1].ToString();
                String ControllerXML = dataRowView[2].ToString();
                DumpAsTxt(ControllerXML.ToString(), "ResultaatID-" + ControllerID + ".txt");
                //This is the code which will show the button click row data. Thank you.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2 :

```
    private void DLButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                DumpAsTxt(ConDatagrid.SelectedItem.XMLCode.ToString(), "ControllerXML.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

And AllDataInTable :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Controller> AllDatainTable { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Controller>();
    public void UpdateTest()
    {
        AllDatainTable.Clear();
        foreach (var item in GetAllDatainTable()) AllDatainTable.Add(item);
    }

    public static List<Controller> GetAllDatainTable()
    {

        using (var context = new EFContext())
        {
            return context.Controllers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The MVVM way to do this would be to bind the `SelectedItem` property to an object, and the button to a Command that looks at the new property and returns the XML that way. However to resolve the conversion errors, give the DataGrid a name and use `dataGrid1.SelectedItem` this should already be your type so should have a .XMLCode property

Comment: @RyanThomas Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to see where I should use the selected item though. For my attempt, I need controllerXML to be in a txt file. How would using selected item know that I need the controllerXML column. I currently have it like this DumpAsTxt(ConDatagrid.SelectedItem.ToString(), "ResultaatID-" + ControllerID + ".txt"); Which wields an entire different error

Comment: In your DLButton_Click you should be able to do something like `(ConDatagrid.SelectedItem as MyObject).XMLCode` are you able to share your class for the object represented in AllDatainTable?

Comment: @RyanThomas I am yes, not that exciting though. It grabs the entire table so I can use it for displaying it on the datagrid. Using the click event as I have in my edited answer gives a "Object does not contain a definition for .xmlcode" error

Comment: Can you try `(ConDatagrid.SelectedItem as Controller).XMLCode`

Comment: No worries, I will post as a proper answer shortly so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the button does not know anything about the Row it belongs too. So to fix your method first give the DataGrid a name (ConDatagrid) then make the below changes.

```
private void DLButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var selectedItem = ConDatagrid.SelectedItem as Controller;
        String ControllerID = selectedItem.Name;
        String ControllerXML = selectedItem.XMLCode;
        DumpAsTxt(ControllerXML, "ResultaatID-" + ControllerID + ".txt");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```